# changing variables to other symbols through the code

Tags: symbols

How can i change variables symbols throughout the entire code without having to change it one by one. So for example A=20 and then 2*A=40; should change to B=20 and 2*B=40.

Comment: tried the front end find/replace menu?

Comment: Make sure to use the "whole word" option in the front end find/replace menu.

Comment: Use `ReplaceAll`: `expr /. A -> B`.